# How do you call a graph which is a simplification of another one

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

The upper graph ($G_1$) seems to be "inside" the lower one ($G_2$). If I understand the definition of a subgraph correctly, $G_1$ is not a subgraph of $G_2$ because there is no A->B and C->D edge in $G_2$.

[image]

Is there a way to say that $G_1$ is a simplified version of $G_2$ ? It is "contained", "included" ... ? Or is there no specific definition for this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Viewing your directed graphs as posets, the former one embeds into the latter.

Comment: I would say a compressed graph, as you can reach B from A faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common term for this is that $G_2$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G_1$.

(I think this more specific to your case than claiming that there’s a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) between the graphs; that’s a symmetric relationship.)

---

If there’s a particular decision rule you used to choose which edges you contracted, I don’t see it. That might lead to a more specific answer.